How do I run the Bipartite Matching and Min Vertex Cover Algorithms on this graph?

Hi, so I am supposed to run the Bipartite Matching and Min. vertex cover Algorithms on this graph (with s = 0 and t = 6) using Ford-Fulkerson and DFS/BFS, "breaking ties in favor of the smaller vertex" (basically if you have two valid paths, choose the one with goes through the smaller vertex).
Bipartite Matching
I added s and added edges connecting to 1, 3, and 5, as well as t with edges to 2 and 4, and then initialized each edge with a capacity of 1. The first augmenting path I chose was 0->1->2->t and filled those with 1s. The next augmenting path I chose was 0->3->2->5->4->6 and filled those with 1s as well. There are no more augmenting paths after this, so the maximum flow is 2. Next, I chose the edges that have a flow of 1 that were in the original graph as the answer, which would be (1,2), (2,3), (2,5), and (5,4). However, this is incorrect. The correct answer is (1,2), (2,5). I understand how to get that- the first augmenting path would be 0->1->2->6, and the second augmenting path would be 0->5->4->6. But isn't choosing those vertices not "breaking ties in favor of the smaller vertex", which is what I was asked to do? I am a bit confused, so if anyone can provide clarification of what I'm doing wrong, I'd really appreciate it.
Minimum Vertex Cover
For vertex cover, I kind of had the same question, as I essentially used the same augmenting paths. The s-t cut I got was through (2,5) and (4,5) (since it matches the max flow of 2 since they both have a capacity of 1) but wouldn't that mean that S = {0,1,2,3,4,5} and since what we need to return is (L\S) U (R ∩ S), which I think would be {2,4}. However, this is incorrect as well- the actual answer is {2,5}.
Sorry if this is a really easy question, I did other problems and got them right and thought I understood how to do these problems, but I guess not. if anyone could help me, I'd really appreciate it! Thank you!

The algorithm used to solve the vertex cover problem goes like this:
LOOP V over vertices
  IF V is a leaf node ( degree 1 )
     Add V to to cover set
LOOP E over edges
  Set V1, and v2 to the vertices connected by E
  IF V1 and V2 are NOT in set
      Set v to V1
      IF V2 degree > V1 degree
           Set v to V2
      Add v to cover set.

